# Не могу решить ошибку Uncaught TypeError: plusButton.addEventListener is not a function

Tags: javascript

Я не понимаю, почему у меня подобная ошибка, когда я делал все по видео уроку, все как у автора, и ошибка.
Как вариант, попробовал через forEach, ошибка в браузере исчезает но код не работает. Несколько часов долблюсь.

```
let numberOne = document.querySelectorAll('.number-one');
let numberTwo = document.querySelectorAll('.number-two');

let plusButton = document.querySelectorAll('.plus');
let clearButton = document.querySelectorAll('.clear');

clearButton.forEach(function(clearBtn) {
  clearBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  numberOne.value = ''
  numberTwo.value = ''
  resultText.innerText = ''
  })
});
  


plusButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
let numOne = parseInt(numberOne.value)
let numTwo = parseInt(numberTwo.value)

let sum = numOne + numTwo

resultText.innerText = sum
});
```

HTML

```html
    <body>
      <div class="wrapper">
        <!-- @import "header.html" -->
        <input type="number" class="number-one">
        <input type="number" class="number-two">
        <button class="plus">+</button>
        <button class="minus">-</button>
        <button class="divide">/</button>
        <button class="multiply">x</button>
        <button class="clear" type="button">Очистить</button>
    
        <p class="result"></p>
    
        <div class="slides"></div>
    
        
    
        <!-- @import "footer.html" -->
      </div>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
    </body>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

Comment: html в студию...

Comment: @Андрей Стешенко
добавил

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Когда вам нужна коллекция элементов, чтобы перебрать её в `forEach()`, используйте `document.querySelectorAll()`. Когда вам нужен один элемент, используйте `document.querySelector()` (без `All`). Вы же используете метод получения коллекции везде, поэтому и получаете такую ошибку — ведь метод `addEventListener()` есть только у элементов, а не у их коллекций.

Comment: тогда почему не работает код где я использовал forEach()? И непонятно, почему у автора видео все работает без forEach(). Видео за 26 января 2021, что то поменялось в javascript?

Comment: @RayOver Потому что в обработчике, который вы привязываете, вы продолжаете использовать коллекции элементов так, будто используете элементы — пытаетесь назначить `value` коллекции вместо элемента, например.

Comment: @RayOver Судя по вашему HTML, вам вообще не нужны ни `querySelectorAll()`,  ни `forEach()` — у вас по одному элементу на класс, поэтому используйте `querySelector()` и ничего не перебирайте, работайте с элементом напрямую.

Comment: спасибо большое, теперь все понял, более того, у автора и использовался document.querySelector() (без All), это моя невнимательность, при этом около двух часов искал проблему. Стыдно.

Comment: @RayOver Ничего, так приобретается опыт)